# Call SQL with a compute clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sybase

Does anybody know how to invoke a SQL command with a compute clause in C#? I'm getting an internal error 30016:

```
Internal Error :30016 Unknown Dataitem Dataitem
```

My Database is Sybase 12.5.4.

Comment: without more info. you are unlikely to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

without more info, your best bet is to wrap it in a stored procedure, and just call that from C#

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason why you couldn't just inline the SQL.

```
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SalesPersonID, CustomerID, OrderDate, SubTotal, TotalDue " +
    "FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader " + 
    "ORDER BY SalesPersonID, OrderDate " + 
    "COMPUTE SUM(SubTotal), SUM(TotalDue) BY SalesPersonID";
```